# Practical applications of operator overloading?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm trying to understand more about the practical uses of operator overloading so i can use them effectively in my code.

Could you describe the general scenario's in which overloading is often useful? Perhaps provide some brief examples?

So far I am aware of the following:

1) Using overloading with STL algorithms is a common example:

```
class Example
{
 public:
   int operator()(int i)
   {
      return i+10;
   }
};

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> V{1,2,3,4,5};
   std::transform(V.begin(), V.end(), V.begin(), Example());
}
```

Although I suppose this is now slightly redundant with the lambda feature.

2) Manipulating object members:

```
class Example
{
 public:
   int some_variable {0};
   Example() {};
   Example(int x) : some_variable{x} {};

   Example operator+(Example &EO)
   {
      Example EO3;
      EO3.some_variable = some_variable + EO.some_variable;
      return EO3;
   }
};

int main()
{
  Example EO1(100);
  Example EO2(200);
  Example EO3 {EO1 + EO2};
}
```

Comment: How about [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and other [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)? The [input and output streams](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io) which overload the shift operators? The [`std::complex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) class (or any class emulating some kind of mathematical concept)? And that's just scratching the surface, there are many more uses of overloaded operators.

Comment: You should use operator overloading when it is natural, that is arithmetic operators are very useful for say a matrix class. You should not use operator overloading to do something only you understand, there it's better to just use a normal function.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude IMHO overloading shift for streams was a terrible idea.

Comment: @Jonas: everything new that is deployed is known only to its own developers until it becomes popular... The point is another: are your objects justifying an "algebra" allowing to form expressions and a domain-specific sub-language? Are operation unambiguously definable or do them require some kind of interpretation?

Comment: There's also the example of [boost::format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/format/doc/format.html) where they overloaded `operator%` to get something similar to Python.

Comment: Saying "There are either too many possible answers" even before there are two looks like ... "ejaculatio precox"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Operator overloading is nothing else than function overloading. It is commonly used between classes that represent objects for which it is possible to define some kind of algebra allowing to form expressions or domain-specific sub-languages.

A typical case of algebraic object as `std::complex` [see reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex), which are ... numbers, hence participating in numeric expressions.

Another example is `std::vector` and `std::array` that model indexed based container, hence overload the `[]` operator.

`std::valarray` adds arithmetic to vectors, so it also implements `+-*/` as well as many mathematical functions (like `sin`, `cos`, `tan`, `sqrt`...)

Another example is `std::shared_ptr` that emulates a pointer, so it overloads the unary `*` and `->`, or iterators of various kind that emulate pointers and iterations on a collection, so overload `*` `->` `==` `!=` `++` `--` `+=` `-=`

An example of domain-specific sub-language is `std::iostream` overloading `<<` and `>>` for input/output, or `boost::spirit`([see](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html)) that uses operators to form EBNF-like expressions.

Comment: You are right, I would like to point out, that it is often important (but not required) to stick with natural working of built-in types, so the user of interface doesn't get into situation where code does something totally unexpected. As example your own implementation of algebraic vector, which instead of sum does subtraction and other mystical things. :-)

Comment: @holmics: I don't really understand why -when it's time to do operator overloading, some people are sooooo scary about them to require useless (even not silly) distinctions: using `+` to subtract is not different than doing a subtraction with an `add` function. But I never see this kind of notes about function overloading.  I also cited `boost::spirit` as a clean example of algebra not following built-in types, proper self-centered rules. although being anyhow useful. So I don't really understand what your fear is about.

Comment: Garvaglia: I don't say, that you are required to implement operators that way. I just said, that recommendation is to follow common sense. If you have domain specific case, such as parsing, overloading  operators will be done differently than in some numeric types.  It is not about being scared, it is about ease of use of interface. You should not do something, just because you can. :-) Implementing + operator to do something like substraction in numeric types wouldn't be much self-explaining and efficient. And that was the message I just wanted to share. :-)